# robotframework multiline regexp

Tags: robotframework

Good Morning,

I apologize but I'm stuck with RobotFramework.
I'm currently trying to compare my system output in JSON with my expected output.

Expected JSON Output, in Robot Framework format:

```
${expected_output}=  Catenate  SEPARATOR=\n
   ...  \ \ "id": "AAAAA-2017-07-21",
    ...  \ \ "version": "2",
    ...  \ \ "creationDateTime": "1500636720",
    ...  \ \ "passengers": {
    ...  \ \ \ \ "1": {
    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ "names": [{
    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "firstName": "TOTO",
    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "lastName": "TUTU"
    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ }],
    ...  \ \ \ \ },
    ...  \ \ \ \ "2": {
    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ "id": "1",
    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ "names": [{
    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "firstName": "TATA",
    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "lastName": "TUTU"
    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ }],
    ...  \ \ \ \ }
    ...  \ \ },
```

Doing the following actions works well,

```
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${output.rc}    0
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${output.stdout}  ${expected_output}
Should Match Regexp ${output.stdout}  "(names|1)"
```

but my point is that I'd like to be able to parse multiple lines, for instance, I would like to compare only the first passenger info and I really don't care about the rest of my output message.

```
...  \ \ \ \ "1": {
...  \ \ \ \ \ \ "names": [{
...  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "firstName": "TOTO",
...  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "lastName": "TUTU"
...  \ \ \ \ \ \ }],
...  \ \ \ \ },
```

I only want to be sure that in my whole message, the above lines are correct, and not check the remaing of my message.

I don't really know how to do that, I've seen that I could use (?m) for multiple line checking,
but I don't know how to use it, and it does not work at all :(

Should it be someting like:

```
Should Match Regexp (?m)    ...  \ \ \ \ "1": {
(?m)    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ "names": [{
(?m)    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "firstName": "TOTO",
(?m)    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "lastName": "TUTU"
(?m)    ...  \ \ \ \ \ \ }],
(?m)    ...  \ \ \ \ },
```

I'm totally lost, could you please help me?

Thanks in advance,
Regards.
Thomas

Comment: Did you noticed HTTPLibrary and its json capabilities? http://peritus.github.io/robotframework-httplibrary/HttpLibrary.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting back structured data, regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job.

You don't say what library you're using to fetch the JSON data. There's a good chance that library has a way to convert the JSON data to a python object. For example, the requests library lets you convert the output to a python object with something like `${result.json()}`.

Once you've converted the JSON object to a real object, you can directly address any part of the data using robot's extended variable syntax.

The following example uses python's json decoder to convert the actual value to an object, then verifies the first name of the first passenger:

```
${actual}=  evaluate  json.loads('''${output.stdout}''')  json
Should be equal  ${actual["passengers"]["1"]["names"][0]["firstName"]}  TOTO
```

You could use the same technique to compare the whole dictionary, by setting your expected value to just the values you want to compare

```
${expected}=  Catenate
...  {
...    "names": [{
...        "firstName": "TOTO",
...        "lastName": "TUTU"
...    }]
...  }
${expected}=  evaluate  json.loads('''${expected}''')  json
${actual}=  evaluate  json.loads('''${output.stdout}''')  json

Dictionaries should be equal  ${actual["passengers"]["1"]}  ${expected}
```

Note: `Dictionaries should be equal` is from the [Collections](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html) library

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll test it very soon :)

Comment: Can I ask another question related to this one?

Actually, in my JSON structure there is also a field that contains the date and time from when it test was performed...

So this mean that the date will always change... so I've got an issue here... 

is there a way to say:
Compare everything except the filed date?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Totoc1001: the simplest solution is to simply remove the dates from the actual and expected values before doing the comparison.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, this is not an option... :(
I mean, I cannot change removing the date from the expected output...
Do you seen another way?

Comment: @Totoc1001: why can't you remove the expected data? You're the one creating the expected data.

Comment: @Totoc1001: the other solution is to write your own keyword that compares only the parts of the data you care about.

Comment: Because the code is not mine... and it is required to have the date...
Your second point is exactly what I want to do...
Is it possible?

Comment: For instance, I had this before:
`...    "names": [{
...        "firstName": "TOTO",
...        "lastName": "TUTU",
...         "MyField":"TITI"
...    }]`

and now in MyField I will get:
`TITI2017-06-20T13:04:00`

Is it possible to have a keyword saying:
in this path the only check the field TITI?